# Connect to MySQL DB from another network with restricted IP Address

Tags: mysql

As I know we can create Users like:

1. 'Test01'@'localhost' (which means Test01 can access to MYSQL DB only from localhost)
2. 'Test01'@'192.168.0.150' (which means Test01 can access to MYSQL DB only from internal network with the client having 192.168.0.150 IP address)
3. 'Test01'@'%' (which means all IP can access)

What I want to achieve is to allow Test01 to access MySQL DB from **ANOTHER** network (example public IP: 1.2.3.4) and this network has a client with static local IP 192.168.0.150, where I want to restrict only this local IP can access mySQL DB.

If I create user like 'Test01'@'1.2.3.4', this will allow all the local IP under '1.2.3.4' to connect to mySQL DB, where I only want a single client with static IP 192.168.0.150 to connect to mySQL DB.

MySQL server is already exposed to the internet via port forwarding.

Can we possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

**Log in to your MySQL server** by using the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your root password after it prompts for it

Use `GRANT command` to enable access for the remote user. Here db implies as database name, dbuser as database user and ip-address as the remote IP from where it is going to be accessed.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON db.* TO dbuser@'ip-address' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

Above `GRANT command` grants ALL permissions to the dbuser to connect from the specified IP address by using the specified password.

Finally test the connection remotely:

```
mysql -u dbuser -p -h ip-address
Enter password:
```